# ValueError all the input array dimensions for the concatenation axis must match exactly

Tags: python, machine-learning, conv-neural-network, generative-adversarial-network

I'm trying to make a GAN to generate art

full code https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1SdmXZZF4J9SmkE3jrNoE0TOzIwLRfnfO?usp=sharing

but I get this error

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-37-215cb31237cb> in <module>()
----> 1 train(600,50)

<ipython-input-36-1e2e312bb297> in train(epochs, batch_size)
     15       #generate fake images
     16       generated_images = generator.predict(noise)
---> 17       X = np.concatenate([image_batch, generated_images])
     18 
     19       #labels for fake + real

<__array_function__ internals> in concatenate(*args, **kwargs)

ValueError: all the input array dimensions for the concatenation axis must match exactly, but along dimension 1, the array at index 0 has size 100 and the array at index 1 has size 28
```

I understand the error but I can't find where the error is coming from

```
def train(epochs=1, batch_size=50):
  x_train = load_data()
  batch_count = x_train.shape[0] / batch_size
  adam = get_optimizer()
  generator = get_generator(adam)
  discriminator = get_discriminator(adam)
  gan = get_gan_network(discriminator, random_dim, generator, adam)
  #random noise and images
  for e in range(1, epochs+1):
    print("-"*15,"Epoch %d" % e, "-"*15)
    for _ in tqdm(range(int(batch_count))):
      noise = np.random.normal(0, 1, size=[batch_size, random_dim])
      image_batch = x_train[np.random.randint(0, x_train.shape[0], size=batch_size)]
      
      #generate fake images
      generated_images = generator.predict(noise)
      X = np.concatenate([image_batch, generated_images])

      #labels for fake + real
      y_dis = np.zeros(2*batch_size)
      y_dis[:batch_size] = 0.9

      discriminator.trainable = True 
      discriminator.train_on_batch(X, y_dis)

      noise = np.random.normal(0, 1, size=[batch_size, random_dim])
      y_gen = np.ones(batch_size)
      discriminator.trainable = False
      gan.train_on_batch(noise, y_gen)

    if e == 1 or e % 20 == 0:
      plot_generated_images(e, generator)
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: Please include the relevant code in your question, linking to a 3rd party site is inconvenient for many different reasons. Paste the _full_ error message as well, we should have some sort of line number to reference.

Comment: @taylorthurlow full error message added